# New to git - trouble understanding why a directory is null

Tags: git, null

I'm trying to move an existing project into a new git repo

**So far I've:**

1. Created a new repo in Github
2. Cloned it locally
3. Copied all the project files into the repo directory
4. Staged all the files
5. Done an initial commit

But one of the directories didn't commit and when I view it in Tower (Mac OSX GUI) the directory looks like this:

```
directory-name -> (null)
```

**So I then:**

1. Removed the directory
2. Staged and committed that change
3. Copied the directory into the repo again
4. Staged and committed the new copy of the directory

But the directory is still sitting in the staging area as (null).

What is wrong with the directory that would cause this? Or is it something inside the directory?

If I select the directory in tower, I can see the following in the diff section:

```
- Subproject commit 9c9af5520163c9980adf780d527dd5a830ec4fe5
+ Subproject commit 9c9af5520163c9980adf780d527dd5a830ec4fe5-dirty
```

I've searched around but I don't fully understand the other answers sorry - any help or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, your the directory, you're talking about, is empty or contains only files which are ignored by your git configuration. GIT does not tracks empty directories.

Comment: Thanks for that - the directory contains 2 other directories and both have files in them. There was a .gitignore file in that directory, so I deleted it but still no luck.

Comment: Actually, viewing the directory in the terminal, there was another .git directory - I removed it and now the directory has gone from the working directory possible from the sass framework I downloaded. So all good now! Cheers